# Is there slowdown inserting into an InnoDB table that has no index set?

Tags: mysql, performance, index, innodb, insert

I have an old application with lots of InnoDB tables, that have no indexes at all, not even a primary ID or such.

Those tables only contain a few thousand rows.

Would it be faster to `INSERT` data into these tables if I would set a primary index (that I don't need otherwise)?

Answer (score 1):

On the contrary, a table with no indexes would be faster to run INSERTs on than a table with indexes.

However, in the case of InnoDB, there is already an internal index in use called the [**gen_clust_index**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-index-types.html). It is also better known as the Clustered Index. It exists for all InnoDB tables, even those with no PRIMARY KEY.

I have written about the [**gen_clust_index**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-index-types.html) before

- `Sep 20, 2011` : [Best of MyISAM and InnoDB](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5974/best-of-myisam-and-innodb/6008#6008)
- `Mar 27, 2013` : [Are there implicit indexes in InnoDB like MyISAM?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/37643/are-there-implicit-indexes-in-innodb-like-myisam/38690#38690)
- `Feb 24, 2011` : [what is gen_clust_index used for in mysql? (ServerFault)](https://serverfault.com/questions/238845/what-is-gen-clust-index-used-for-in-mysql/239554#239554)

Thus, adding a PRIMARY KEY on an InnoDB table with no PRIMARY KEY buys you nothing but another index.

Another headache in this regard is the fact that all lookups must eventually end up in the gen_clust_index, especially with secondary indexes. In fact, loadding data into an InnoDB table with secondary indexes will pile up changes in the Insert Buffer of the System Tablespace ([**See Pictorial Representation of ibdata1**](http://www.scribd.com/doc/31337494/XtraDB-InnoDB-internals-in-drawing))

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this (as my tables usually have at least a primary key) but I expect the difference to depend on the choice of the primary key.

Based on the information in MySQL documentation about InnoDB engine, all InnoDB tables have a clustered index. This is the `PRIMARY` key of the table and in lack of one, the first `UNIQUE` index. And in lack of unique keys as well, a hidden column is created (and values are auto-generated for it) and used internally for unique identification and for clustering.

The "key" here is that this hidden column is a 6-byte integer column. So, you have 6 bytes per row overhead when you don't define primary and any unique index in an InnoDB table.

In contrast, if you have a narrower column (like a 1, 2, 3 or 4 byte integer auto-incrementing column) defined as primary or unique index , you should expect an improvement on `INSERT` efficiency.

If you define an 8-byte integer I'd expect a decrease on efficiency.

If it is a `VARCHAR(20)` or a wider combination of column, the decrease would probably be worse, depending on the order you provide the PK values. Auto-incrementing values are by definition increasing (so good for a clustered index). If you provide non-increasing values, that will affect the `INSERT` efficienct negatively.